# REST webservice doesn't receive Android HttpPost parameters

Tags: java, android, web-services, http-post

I have a webservice which receives 2 (optional) parameters:

```
<resource path="getLogbookEvents">
   <method name="POST">
     <request>
        <param name="startDate" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
        <param name="endDate" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
     </request>
     <response>
        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
     </response>
   </method>
</resource>
```

I'm able to connect and receive an answer from Android using HttpPost, but the web service never receives either of the two parameters.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://... method URL ...");
//post.setHeader("media-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startDate", "2014-04-18T05:00:00"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("endDate", "2014-04-18T06:00:00"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);

// entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
post.setEntity(entity);

// make POST request to the given URL
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(post);

// receive response as inputStream
inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

I have tried HttpParams, JSONObject and nameValuePairs and nothing works. I just keep receiving the response as if I didn't specify any parameters. Any ideas on why this could be happening or other things I could try to get the winning combination?

Comment: check database in startdate and enddate field structure..

Comment: The startdate and enddate structure is definitely correct. I get the right data if I request it using the same values with SoapUI.

Comment: but why you type string in type="xs:string" in webservice api... you can get start and end date in date format.

Comment: use type="xs:dateTime" in webservice api

Comment: I'm not actually able to edit the webservice, sadly. I could try to get the people responsible to change it if need be, but seeing as it expects a string and a string is sent as a parameter, my issue of not receiving the values should not be related to the values not being specified as dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working.

So, first of all, there's definitely something wrong with the webservice.
I'm not exactly sure what, and it's not my business to fix it, so I'm not even going to try to pinpoint what it was.

Basically, the getLogbookEvents wasn't receiving parameters because it won't accept any parameters inside the body of the request, period. Looking at the SoapUI raw data being sent I discovered that it was always sending the parameters inside the URL, not the body ...

I have no idea how they got a POST method to behave like a GET method, but as it stands they apparently do. Formatting my nameValuePairs in UTF-8 and adding them to the URL is the (totally backwards and not recommended at all) way I got it to work :)

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startDate", "2014-04-18T05:00:00"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("endDate", "2014-04-18T06:00:00"));

String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("... basic URL String ..." + paramString);
```

Answer (score 1):

not a direct answer, never used httpclient directly but to debug/fix this issue you could:

- use proxy and see what data is really being sent from your phone
- use easy to use http libs such as [http-request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request)
- or [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

go for http-request. it is dead simple to use. trust me.

Comment: I'll see if that helps this afternoon. But since I'm already getting an answer, it should be perfectly possible to specify the parameters with the way I'm doing it now. Which is really starting to piss me off because I can't figure out what's going wrong.